# How to write $\frac{27-17x}{2x^2-x+1}$ as a series to solve this recurrence relations problem?

Tags: sequences-and-series, recurrence-relations, generating-functions

The relation is:

$$a_n=a_{n-1}-2a_{n-2}+4^{n-2}$$
$$a_0=2, a_1=1$$

I managed to reduce the problem to the generating function:

$$A(x)=\frac{2-9x+5x^2}{(1-4x)(1-x+2x^2)}$$

and then I got this:

$$A(x)=\frac{1}{14}\left(\frac{27-17x}{2x^2-x+1}-\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty(-1)4^nx^n\right)$$

How can I write the remaining fraction as a series so I can solve the recurrence relation?

Comment: The sum goes over $i$, but $n$ occurs. A typo ?

Comment: Yes, just a typo.

Comment: I just need to find the formula for $a_n$

Comment: Formula for the solution of the rec. relation dependant only on n.

Comment: $a_n= \frac{1}{7} 2^{\frac{n}{2}-1} \left(2^{3 n/2}-\sqrt{7} \sin \left(n \tan
   ^{-1}\left(\sqrt{7}\right)\right)+27 \cos \left(n \tan ^{-1}\left(\sqrt{7}\right)\right)\right)$ (used Mathematica). I don't feel to do this by hand unless you explicitly ask for. But it is somewhat standard...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not going to be particularly pretty, but the standard way (as is done with the Fibonacci sequence, for example) is to let
$$
2x^2 - x + 1 = (x - \alpha) (x - \beta)
$$
for complex $\alpha, \beta$ (it will probably save you work to name them $\alpha$ and $\beta$ rather than giving them explicitly with the quadratic formula).  Then solve the partial fractions decomposition
$$
\frac{27x - 17}{2x^2 - x + 1} = \frac{A}{x - \alpha} + \frac{B}{x - \beta}
$$
and you should end up with a representation
$$
a_n = c_1 \alpha^n + c_2 \beta^n + c_3 4^n.
$$
Of course, you can solve for $c_1, c_2, c_3$ directly by plugging in a few values of $n$.

Comment: Thank you very much. Wolfram Alpha shows that $a_0$ is approx. 2 and $a_1$ is approx. 1 so it looks good. [Link](http://imgur.com/a/5rcAb#0) so others can see the solution since I'm too lazy to type it out.